# what do these words mean? 들어군요, 찬다는, 하다가제, 어케, 몰아가기,정, 천리마띠로,묶는, 이내, 정조 글씨

Tags: vocabulary

들어군요, 찬다는, 하다가제,  어케, 몰아가기,정, 천리마띠로,묶는, 이내, 정조 글씨

동기 언니가 CCTV 확인해 보자고 확인하러 가려는 찰나에 갑자기 동기 오빠가 손을 [[슥]] 들어군요.

그래서 제가 자리에 멈춰서 쳐다만 보고 있으니까 기가 [[찬다는]] 표정으로

그래서 아 저는 진짜 진짜 괜찮다고 이런 실랑이를 계속 [[하다가제]] 등을 떠밀더군요.

그 선배는 너무 늦었다며 너 그런일도 있었는데 내가 너 택시태워서 신경쓰여서 [[어케]] 보내냐는 식이었습니다.

그치만 무작정 이상한 사람으로 [[몰아가기엔]] 앞으로 제 사회생활이 걸려있으니 최대한 자연스럽게대화를 끝내려고 했습니다.

매트리스를 들어서 [[정]] 가운데 넣어놨더라구요.

하루 종일 [[천리마띠로]] 현수를 업고 엄마가 돌아오기를 눈이 빠져라 기다렸다.

그리고 자료를 보여주겠다며 회사에서 [[묶는]] 리조트로 가자고 하더군요.

다른 하나는, 우여곡절 끝에 내건 한자 현판(光化門)이 [[이내]] 갈라지는 바람에 일어난 부실 복원 논란이었다.

유 청장은 현판 교체 대상이 왜 하필 [[정조]] 글씨여야 하느냐는 논란에 대해서는 "그것은 (문화재청이 생각하는) 여러 안(案) 중 하나"이며 고궁(古宮) 품격에 맞추기 위해 ...

Comment: `슥` is an onomatopoeic word for moving hands. `기가 찬다` is a synonym of `기가 막힌다`. `하다가제` looks like a typo. It's probably supposed to be `하다가 제`. `어케` is a casual version of `어떻게`.

Answer (score 1):

- 들어군요: a typing error for 들더군요. 들더군요 = 들다(to lift) + -더군 + 요 (a politeness particle).
- 찬다는 = 차다(to be filled) + -ㄴ다는
  (기가 차다 is an idiom used when you cannot say anything because something is outrageous).
- 하다가제: a typing error for 하다가 제. 하다가 = 하다(to do) + -다가. 제 here means "my."
- 어케: an informal and incorrect form for 어떻게(how).
- 몰아가기 = 몰아가다(to drive someone/something towards) + -기(a nominalizer).
  ("나를 범인으로 몰아가지 마." is like "Don't think of me as a culprit.")
- 정 = right (as in "right in the center").
- 천리마띠로: a typing error for 천리마 띠로 (천리마 modifies 띠). This 띠 refers to a sling. 천리마 refers to a horse that can go 1000 리 (리 is a unit of length).
- 묶는: a typing error for 묵는. 묵는 = 묵다(to stay as in "staying at a hotel") + -는.
- 이내: right away or soon.
- 정조: the 22nd ruler of the Joseon Dynasty of Korea.